# need help writing hexadecimals to an exe file

Tags: vb.net, exe, hex

can somone tell me how to write these hexadecimals to an  exe file while still having it exec

---

```
4D 5A 50 00 02 00 00 00 04 00 0F 00 FF FF 00 00 B8 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 40 00 1A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 BA 10 00 0E 1F 
B4 09 CD 21 B8 01 4C CD 21 90 90 54 68 69 73 20 70 72 6F 67 72 61 6D 
20 6D 75 73 74 20 62 65 20 72 75 6E 20 75 6E 64 65 72 20 57 69 6E 33 
32 0D 0A 24 37 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

//  Removed approximately 400 similar lines from the original posting.
//  (no point to be so verbose...)

40 FC C3 E8 F3 FF FF FF 48 C3 90 55 8B EC FF 75 08 E8 51 FB FF FF 5D 
C2 04 00 90 E9 3B F9 FF FF C3 8B C0 E8 9B 01 00 00 C3 8B C0 55 8B EC 
83 C4 E0 53 56 57 89 4D F8 8B F2 89 45 FC 8B 5D FC 8B 1B 8B 45 08 8B 
38 85 FF 7F 1A 85 FF 7D 07 B0 04 E8 DE E0 FF FF 8B 45 FC 8B D6 E8 C4 
FF FF FF E9 4A 01 00 00 33 C0 89 45 F0 85 DB 74 0B 83 EB 04 8B 03 89 
45 F0 83 EB 04 33 C0 8A 46 01 01 C6 8B C6 8B 50 02 89 55 E8 8B 5
```

Comment: Perhaps you didn't need to post them all. After the first few, I think i got the idea.

Comment: You're effectively trying to edit a file while it's open by another process. Worse, it's a binary file. Even worse, it's an executable. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Useless reply: If you don't know how to write binary data, you have no business writing it to EXE files.